# Bold \varepsilon not as bold as it should be!

Tags: pdftex, bold, characters

So when I use `\bm{\varepsilon}` and `\bm{\epsilon}`, the latter is LOT more highlighted.

How can I make `\varepsilon` as bold as the rest of the symbols?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fleqn}
\usepackage{amsmath} %%I am adding this!
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\title{Whatever}
\author{AB}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\showoutput
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon \epsilon \bm{\varepsilon} \bm{\epsilon}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you mean to have backslashes in those \bm?

Comment: Please always post a complete document starting with `\documentclass` so we can reproduce the problem (and you can test the posted code)

Comment: I don't understand. Looks normal to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SuBBj.png

Comment: Oh good grief that is why you should _always_ include a full document. You are using a non standard font setup so the image I posted is irrelevant, I'll update.

Answer (score 10):

Once the obvious errors are fixed such that you get an epsilon, they look bold to me:

[image]

Both are coming from the computer modern bold symbol font so are as designed by the font designer (D. Knuth in this case) and the boldness can't really be changed other than by changing fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}

\showoutput
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon \epsilon \bm{\varepsilon} \bm{\epsilon}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

since I answered, you changed the question.

[image]

You are presumably seeing the top image with the non bold coming from mathpazo
and teh bold coming from cm.

The `bm` package does tell you it has to be loaded *after* you have changed the math setup so it can find the bold fonts. If you load the packages in the correct order you get the lower version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\showoutput
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon \epsilon \bm{\varepsilon} \bm{\epsilon}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps `\pmb{\bm{\epsilon}}` ?

Comment: @jfbu please, no:-)

Comment: \pmb does work, but it is now too bold in comparison with the rest of the \bm{} characters. Without it, for some reason, it is not as bold as the rest of the \bm{} symbols. Is there a way to control the boldness with \pmb somehow? Thank you!

Comment: @user2822693 in what way do you think the image as posted is "not as bold" ?

Comment: Ok. Good point! I printed on a different printer, it looks ok now. Sorry.. and thank you for your replies!

Comment: @user2822693 no the output you will get from your MWE is wrong (see my updated answer)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, I get it maybe @user2822693 wants `\pmb{\pmb{\bm{\epsilon}}}` ! it looks _funny_ at `1000%` zoom `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu any more of that and I''ll send you to egreg.